# Cannot Open Specified Excel File

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error for my hyperlink saying "cannot open the specified file". I have checked for answers on other forums but nothing has worked so far. I just trying to make a dynamic hyperlink that opens something based on a cell's value. I am not sure if the syntax is wrong or can the only reason be the file path.

```
Public Sub add_hyperlink()
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(Range("A11"), "_")
Range("F11") = arr(2)
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Range("F12"), Address:="C:Users\risha\Downloads\" & Range("A12"), ScreenTip:="Open file", TextToDisplay:="Open File"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's `Range("A12").Value`, to be precise. This range is on the ActiveSheet which, in theory, could be any sheet in any open workbook and must not, therefore, be the one you think. Better specify both the sheet (by name) and the workbook (as *ThisWorkbook*). Then make sure the cell's value includes the file extension. Finally, open the file using the same address with a different command. That's to test the file name. Then, if the file isn't an Excel workbook you may have to create an instance of the required application. Then, finally, look at the hyperlink syntax.